# Getting an objects property with slashes in it

Tags: php, freebase

I'm getting a json result back from an api request to the freebase database.
This is part of the object returned called $json. A var dump of $json:

```
stdClass Object
(
[name] => Abomey
[/location/statistical_region/population_growth_rate] => 
[/common/topic/article] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => /m/0jk2c
            )
    )
```

How can I subtract the /m/0jk2c part?

$json->/common/topic/article[0]->id (obviously) doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$json->{"/common/topic/article"}[0]->id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should use

```
 $class->{'/location/statistical_region/population_growth_rate'}['/common/topic/article'][0]->id
```

Reason your Object looks like this

```
$std = new stdClass();
$std->id = '/m/0jk2c' ;

$json  = new stdClass();
$json->name = "Abomey" ;
$json->{'/location/statistical_region/population_growth_rate'} = array('/common/topic/article'=>array($std));
```

If you run

```
var_dump($json->{'/location/statistical_region/population_growth_rate'}['/common/topic/article'][0]->id);
```

Output

```
string '/m/0jk2c' (length=8)
```

Run

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Abomey
    [/location/statistical_region/population_growth_rate] => Array
        (
            [/common/topic/article] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => /m/0jk2c
                        )

                )

        )

)
```